# Using lagged independent variable in place of its current value

Tags: panel-data, dataset, lags

I am estimating the impact of migration on a binary outcome (employment) using Diff-and-Diff with multiple periods in an unbalanced panel data (with non-migrants as a control group). To this end, one of the controls that I am using is family size (number of children). Given that the number of children is likely to affect whether or not someone migrates in the first place, I am controlling for family size before intervention (migration for migrants; adjusted to mean age before migration for non-migrants).

Pairwise correlation between the two variables = 0.5406; lrtest shows strong preference for the model with both lag & current value as opposed to just lag.

Is there any justification for only including a lagged value, i.e. family size before intervention, instead of including both (family size current value in addition to its lag?) As a side note, in addition, I also control for whether or not the respondents had small children in each year (equal to 1 for years when respondents had small children).

Any insights will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be reasons for including only lag but it’s hard to say from your description. For example, if there is endogeneity between employment and number of children then you could justify using only lagged number of children, as lags can often serve as instruments for contemporaneous variables and you can interpret including only lag as reduced form of IV

Comment: Many thanks for this. Is there any way to check if it is endogenous? I am using stata and this is a binary log regression so I do not seem to be able to do it via estat endogenous command. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kase there are but they come with big caveats. You could use granger causality test, stata command vargranger but it only checks for granger causality which is not the same as true underlaying causality. So even if test shows there is no endogeneity you can’t be sure just from test. You could do Hausman test command hausman but this test requires a set of valid instruments and it’s hypotheses are set in a way that you can only know if IV regression will be more consistent than OLS so again it does not tell you much. Best way is to check theory which should tell you if there is endogeneity

Comment: In this case, am I right in assuming that I will be on the safe side if I include both?

Comment: @Kase unfortunately no, there really aren’t safe sides in econometrics. If you include both and there actually is endogeneity then you have biases estimates, unless you include them in something like IV. However, even then if you do IV when it’s not necessary it would lead to high loss of efficiency and hence precision. If you include only lagged variable but the contemporaneous variable is not endogenous and it is relevant you get omitted variable bias. The only safe side is to ground your model in economic intuition, theory and past literature - maybe ask on Econ exchange

Comment: Many thanks for this - I will do as you suggest and dig in a bit further. Thank you!